# Get hex time stamp from bash script

Tags: bash, time

I would like to convert the current date and time into a hex time stamp, something like:

Tue Feb 2 10:27:46 GMT 2010 converted into 0x6d054a874449e

I would like to do this from a bash script, any idea how I might do that?

Thanks
J

Comment: How does that hex translate into a timestamp?  Miliseconds since epoch?  Taking the date as a number and showing it as hex?

Answer (score 10):

```
printf '0x%x' $(date +%s)
```

Comment: Why the example in the answer by Matthew uses `time_t_ms` to convert to hexa, while this answer by mob uses `$(date +%s)` that is in seconds? Tx.

Comment: thanks, let me add: use %X if you need an uppercase hex

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the unit or epoch for your hex timestamp, it's hard to say for sure (and I was slightly confused by your example of "Feb 2" which is not even close to the current date!).

`date +%s` will convert the current date into a `time_t`, the number of seconds since the usual Unix epoch (which is midnight on 1st Jan 1970).

`printf "0x%x" some_number` will convert a value from decimal to hex.

If you need to convert to a different epoch / unit, you will need to do some calculation.  You can do arithmetic in `bash` using `$(( expression ))`:

```
$ time_t=$(date +%s)
$ echo $(($time_t * 1000))
1284505668000
```

If you want to convert an arbitrary date (like your "Feb 2 ..." example), rather than the current one, and are happy to assume that you have the GNU version of `date`, then you can use the `-d` option along with the `+%s` output format to do the conversion:

```
$ date -d 'Tue Feb 2 10:27:46 GMT 2010' +%s 
1265106466
```

An example of putting this all together:

```
$ time_t=$(date -d 'Tue Feb 2 10:27:46 GMT 2010' +%s)
$ time_t_ms=$(($time_t * 1000))
$ hexstamp=$(printf "0x%x" $time_t_ms)
$ echo $hexstamp
0x1268e38b4d0
```

Answer (score 1):

Seconds since unix epoch, in hex:

```
 echo "$(date +%s)"|xargs printf "0x%x"
 0x59a8de5b
```

Milliseconds since the epoch:

```
 echo "$(date +%s%N)/1000000"|bc|xargs printf "0x%x"
 0x15e3ba702bb
```

Microseconds:

```
echo "$(date +%s%N)/1000"|bc|xargs printf "0x%x"
0x55818f6eea775
```

Nanoseconds:

```
echo "$(date +%s%N)"|xargs printf "0x%x"
0x14e0219022e3745c
```